# CAP: Could we sacrifice Availability to gain Partition tolerance?

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed-computing, cap

My understanding: In essence, A and P are the same thing. Because from the perspective of the entire multi-node cluster, AP is always positively correlated: there is basically no way for us to make design choices such as "sacrificing A to get P" or "sacrificing P to get A".

For example: Can you design a high-availability multi-node cluster that does not allow network partitions (that is: once a network partition appears, it will be unavailable)?

Single-node systems are not considered here, because CAP is a law for distributed clusters.

Comment: What are you trying to convey here? How does A and P become the same thing? Partition tolerance is an undeniable constraint while building Distributed system, So how does the example that you pointed out bring any meaning.

https://robertgreiner.com/cap-theorem-revisited/

Comment: So in a distributed system, why is P a feature that cannot be rejected? Isn’t it just because you reject P is equivalent to rejecting A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Therefore, the CAP theory can only be interpreted as: when the multi-node cluster has a network partition (P), **and it is so serious that no partition in the cluster contains the majority nodes**. You can now choose to maintain consistency (C) or maintain availability (A).